# Concatenate collection from property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
class oA {
   int type;
   List<oB> list;
}

class oB {
   int id,
   decimal price,
   string name
}
```

somewhere you get a list from oA objects.

What is the correct way to have 1 list of oB objects from all the oA objects of a certain type?

i was thinking something like this

```
var myoAs = new List<oA>();
/* Load data from wherever */
var myList =  myoAs.Where(x => x.type == 1).select(....)
```

Who knows the anwer how to get a complete list of all the oB objects (and even remove duplicates in the linq as well if possible)

Comment: Read up on `SelectMany` and `Distinct`.

Comment: Also note that a [mcve] is generally a lot more useful than pseudo-code.

Answer (score 4):

Use `SelectMany` to aggregate multiple lists and `Distinct` to filter duplicates.

```cs
var myList =  myoAs.Where(x => x.type == 1).SelectMany(a => a.list).Distinct();
```

Comment: `.Distinct` for reference type, i think you could use it with a custom comparer

Comment: ok will try it in a sec, and then vote your answer up. thx for the fine solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension method

IEnumerable distinctList = myoAs.SelectMany(x=>x.list).DistinctBy(x => x.name);

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    return source.Where(element => knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)));
}
```

Comment: `MoreLINQ` has this in an existing NuGet package.